# Dynamic user input model builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I'm making a costing model.  I need to require the user to input unit costs and then the model will multiply the unit cost by number of units.  How do I add an input box that has no connection to a layer or table?

Comment: Look at the help file on modelbuilder about exposing the inputs and outputs of tool in a model as _parameters_.

Answer (score 3):

Create a [Model Parameter.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000003z000000)

Here is a [tutorial.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000007v000000)